# Asp.net core push notification to Xamarin (Android, IOS)

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-2.0, onesignal

I have an asp.net core api for a delivery tracking system that interacts with xamarin.forms mobile app, I want to send push notification for certain events like order is received or cancelled etc...

I'm new to push notifications, I have tried some examples of sending push notification using FireBase and OneSignal, but could not find any examples for sending these push notification using my asp.net core api.

what are the steps i should follow to make that work ? any link for a working example is all i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easy ways to implement push notification is to use the Appcenter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-forms

follow this documentation.

Appcenter also has an API to send the notification so you can integrate it inside your app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/pushapi

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank for the links but i'm seeking free services, as mentioned in the question, FireBase and OneSignal

Comment: app center uses FireBase. :) check it out.

Comment: Are there any free plans ? other than the  30 days trial ?

Comment: Up to 5 audience segments it is free. you can send any number of push notification available in Firebase

Comment: Okay i'll check that out.

Comment: If you have any experience with app center would you mind guiding me on how to to send notifications to specific user categories, such as drivers, clients, etc.. i found that there is the segments option but that would not help me.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/pushapi#send-notifications-to-device-ids check this